# display selected value on update() function popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i have to onClick function one is for creating new contact and my popup form will appear and this is when my dropdown query will begin running and display the list of dropdown with ng-options. Now my issues is that my another onClick which is to update the contact form will also display the same new query instead of displaying the selected option that i have stored.

I use angular.copy to display the updated form and the console.log show that i have stored my data correctly. What should i do so that when i click on my update contact it will display the matching dropdown value i stored.

This is the html code in my view page.

```
<div class="new_form_group">
    <label class="control_label">Organisation</label>
    {{ contact.courier_org_id}}
    <select ng-model="contact.courier_org_id"                             
     ng-change="org_id_changeValue(item)" ng-selected="contact.courier_org_id" class="form-control input-sm" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in getOrganisationList" >
    <option value="">No Organisation</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

this is my function to get the dropdown list options

```
$scope.getOrgsList = function() {
    $http.post(BASE_URL + 'couriers/contacts/getOrgsList').success(function (data){
        $scope.getOrganisationList = data.orgsList;  //this will return me 6 array of names and id
        $scope.org_id_changeValue = function(item){
            $scope.contactlistdata.courier_org_id = item;
        };
    });
};
```

This is my click event

```
<span ng-click="update(contact)" class="a_blue_link" tooltip="Edit & View" tooltip-palcement="top">{{contact.contact_name}}</span>
```

Update function

```
$scope.update = function (contact) {
    $scope.contact = angular.copy(contact);
    $scope.contact.courier_org_id = 0;
    $scope.getOrgsList();
    $scope.create_contact();
};
```

Comment: i change it didnt work. im thinking if im able to call the update function when i click on update popup because everytime the popup appear the code will rerun the new dropdown list. But i dont know where to do my conditions

Comment: im not a grammar nazi or anything but the grammar errors on this question makes it even harder to understand. Pls re-read it and do the necessary changes